# Unable to run a COM application through Jenkins if no user is logged in

Tags: windows, jenkins, com, rdp

I am running a Jenkins server on a Windows 10 computer, as a service. In one of the Jenkins-jobs I have to perform tests using a COM application. The same computer is also used by the developers in their daily work over RDP, and the Jenkins-job in question is run in the night when no regular developer is using it. But if no user is logged in on the computer or using RDP, the script in the job fails to start the COM application with the following message:

> The server process could not be started because the configured
>   identity is incorrect. Check the username and password.

I found that the issue seems to be that the identity for the COM application is taken from the current interactive user, and if there is none, it fails, see

https://support.microsoft.com/en-my/help/305761/com-server-application-that-uses-interactive-user-identity-fails-to-lo

I cant seem to be able to solve my issue. I see two options:

1. Make sure that a user is logged in when the job is executed
2. Figure out how to run the COM application without an interactive user

For **1** i see the following solutions and why they do not work:

- **Autologin on Windows start, and leave logged-in**: Will not work since we use the computer in our daily work through RDP, which means that the local logged in user will be kicked out since we are only allowed one session at a time.
- **Log in using RDP and then exit using the script `tscon.exe 0 /dest:console` which will leave the session open**. Will not work since we are 15 people in the team using that machine over RDP, and people will forgett to use this command when they log of by the end of the day.

For **2**, i am unable to find a way to do this.

Can I in Windows schedule a user to automaticall be logged in before the job starts? Can i use a second computer and scedule an RDP-session to the first computer, before the job is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody was able to provide a good solution I will input my workardound as an answer and possible solution. What I ended up doing was using a second computer (running Windows) and schedule a task on that computer that every night (before the Jenkins-job starts) opens an RDP-session to the computer running Jenkins. This way the Jenkins job, and the COM-application, has an active user that it can use.

This is how I achieved this:

1. Login to the second computer (i.e. the one not running Jenkins) and open the RDP (Remote Desktop Connection) dialog and click *Show Options*
2. Enter the details for the first computer (i.e. the one running Jenkins). Make sure to uncheck *Always ask for credentials* (you will need to save the credentials to be able to automate this).
3. Save the configuration to an .rdp-file, using *Save As...*
4. **IMPORTANT:** Press connect to connect to the first computer, enter the password and make sure to save it. Also accept any certificates e.t.c. to prevent future warnings/dialogs.
5. Create a bat-file containing the following

   `mstsc C:\Path\To\saved_rdp_file.rdp`
6. Create a task in Windows Sceduler that calls the bat-file created in step 5 every night.
7. *Optional*: If you want to close the rdp-session when Jenkins is done, create a second bats-script and scedule that as well, containing:

   `tasklist /FI "imagename eq mstsc.exe" | find "mstsc.exe" && taskkill /f /im mstsc.exe || echo process "mstsc.exe" is not running`